# Detecting specific character in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe using pandas (/python) that looks like this:

|  | time_s | wow | lat_deg | lon_deg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 1 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 2 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 3 | 6.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 4 | 8.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 5 | 10.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 6 | 12.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 7 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 8 | 16.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 9 | 18.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 10 | 20.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 11 | 22.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

in the `wow` column, it is defined that it has the value of 0 and 1, I wonder how to process that into another dataframe that detects and take the "0" value right before the first and after the last consecutive value of "1":

(0,1,1,1,1,0) <- the "0" taken

it will looks like this

|  | time_s | wow | lat_deg | lon_deg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 5 | 10.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 7 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 10 | 20.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Note: the consecutive value of "1" is random, in that example of mine is 2 that I made for the sake of simplicity, but in actual database it is about 3k to 5k consecutive rows.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create boolean masks for the conditions of `0` adjacent to `1` and filter by using `df.loc`, as follows:

```
m1 = (df['wow'] == 0.0) & (df['wow'].shift(-1) == 1.0)
m2 = (df['wow'] == 0.0) & (df['wow'].shift(1) == 1.0)
df.loc[m1 | m2]
```

Output:

```
    time_s  wow    lat_deg    lon_deg
3      6.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
5     10.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
7     14.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
10    20.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
```