# Deleting specific row (noise) after detecting specific character in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, noise

This is the continuation of the previous problem that i've asked(
[Detecting specific character in Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581017/detecting-specific-character-in-dataframe))

but let me explain it again

I have a dataframe using pandas (/python) that looks like this:

|  | time_s | wow | lat_deg | lon_deg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 1 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 2 | 4.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 3 | 6.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 4 | 8.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 5 | 10.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 6 | 12.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 7 | 14.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 8 | 16.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 9 | 18.0 | 1 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 10 | 20.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| 11 | 22.0 | 0.0 | 35.042628 | -89.978249 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

in the `wow` column, it is defined that it has the value of 0 and 1. Unfortunately, the data that i have, had some noise, that made the total entity (in row) more than it should be (it is actually from 500 data, but due to some noise, it is detected as 507 data)

Therefore, I intended to remove before processing that

The original data looked like this

(...,0,0,0,0,1,1,***1,0,1***,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,...)

**I need to trim the data by deleting the "0" value in between 1 (1,0,1)** so it will become

(...,0,0,0,0,1,1,***1,1***,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,...)

How do I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only need to get rid out the `0` immediately enclosed by a pair of `1` (i.e. only `1 0 1` series considered), you can set a boolean mask and use `.loc` to filter the rows, as follows:

```
m = (df['wow'] == 0.0) & (df['wow'].shift(1) == 1.0) & (df['wow'].shift(-1) == 1.0)
df[~m]
```

### Demo

As your sample data doesn't have this scenario, I have modified the data a bit:

```
print(df)


    time_s  wow    lat_deg    lon_deg
0      0.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
1      2.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
2      4.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
3      6.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
4      8.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
5     10.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249          <== Matching entry to get rid of 
6     12.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
7     14.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249          <== Matching entry to get rid of 
8     16.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
9     18.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
10    20.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
11    22.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249


m = (df['wow'] == 0.0) & (df['wow'].shift(1) == 1.0) & (df['wow'].shift(-1) == 1.0)
df[~m]


    time_s  wow    lat_deg    lon_deg
0      0.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
1      2.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
2      4.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
3      6.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
4      8.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
6     12.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
8     16.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
9     18.0  1.0  35.042628 -89.978249
10    20.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
11    22.0  0.0  35.042628 -89.978249
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try and use shift along with mask dataframe:

```
df[(df['wow'] == 0) & ((df['wow'].shift(1) ==1) | (df['wow'].shift(-1) ==1))]
```

Output:

```
    time_s  wow lat_deg     lon_deg
3   6.0     0.0 35.042628   -89.978249
5   10.0    0.0 35.042628   -89.978249
7   14.0    0.0 35.042628   -89.978249
10  20.0    0.0 35.042628   -89.978249
```